# Lua why does the __gc metamethod is never ran here?

Tags: lua, garbage-collection, ffi, luajit

I'm struggling to understand why is the `__gc` metamethod is not being called here. I immediately removed the reference to `x` and triggered a GC, so why?

```lua
local obj = {}
obj.__index = obj

function obj:__gc()
  print("gc")
end

function new()
  return setmetatable({}, obj)
end

local x = new()
x = nil
collectgarbage()
```

I expect that the GC would collect that `x` and so it would trigger the `__gc` metamethod associated with it.

This is just a minimal reproducible example but to make my goals clear I want to wrap a C data in LuaJIT's ffi to deallocate its memory upon garbage collection.

Comment: `__gc` needs to be a field in the object's metatable but `new` creates an empty metatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found about `ffi.metatype` which allows me to attach a metatable with `__gc` e.g:

```lua
local ffi = require("ffi")
local mt = {}
local obj = ffi.metatype("struct { int x; }", mt)

function mt:__gc()
  print("gc")
end

function new()
  return obj(5)
end

local x = new()
x = nil
collectgarbage()
```

Since I need to wrap a C pointer, this is just right for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `__gc` is supported in the current version of LuaJIT, but it does seem to be planned as part of this really old proposal for a new GC:
https://github.com/LuaJIT/LuaJIT/issues/38, which is linked to this issue: https://github.com/LuaJIT/LuaJIT/issues/47#issuecomment-132403863